# _jcr_content required to call JSP

Tags: jsp, aem

[image: Calling JSON]

I can successfully call the locations.json.jsp by using the following URL in my AJAX call but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way?

This: /content/API/formdata/locations/_jcr_content.locations.json works well but I'm wondering if there is a way to call locations.json in place of locations.html to reach the json version directly without having to have the .jsp version to serve up the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In general, CQ/AEM stores nodes as *resources* - but JSPs themselves aren't that type of content.

If `/content/API/formdata/locations` was a page whose `sling:resourceType` equaled a page/component, you could have a `json.jsp` to provide the JSON rendering of that resource.  However, there should be a clear separation in paths between your content/resource (under `/content`) and the component rendering it (`/apps`).  Your example above doesn't appear to indicate such a separation of concerns.

For example:

- `/content/API/formdata/locations` path to page (which has a jcr:content child node, and any number of children under jcr:content)
- `/apps/myApp/page/myPage` page component having child JSPs of `myPage.jsp`, (or `html.jsp`) and `json.jsp`
- `/content/API/formdata/locations/jcr:content` property `sling:resourceType` = `myApp/page/myPage` (or `/apps/myApp/page/myPage`) describes path to renderer of the resource - allowing multiple "renders" in HTML or JSON format